# Why I can't see the image on Mobile Steam?

Tags: steam

In the steam chat, I can clearly see there's image show out just like this.

[image]

But in my Mobile Steam chat, the image is not show out and it only show the link.

[image]

What is the problem at here?

Comment: I guess this has more to do with your phone's settings than with Steam itself.

Comment: It may be trying to conserve data while not on wifi.

Comment: The wifi is on one.

Comment: Down voter, please explain why you down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last signficant update to the iOS Steam app was in 2015. Embedded images are a relatively new feature in Steam Chat -- they were added as part of the July 2018 [Chat Update](https://steamcommunity.com/updates/chatupdate) -- so the Steam app does not support this feature.

There is, however, a *separate* [Steam Chat](https://apps.apple.com/app/steam-chat/id1434890245?t=1) app which does support this functionality. Why this wasn't made part of the other Steam app is a question that I don't have an answer to.